# Ajax module Popup is Closed after clicking Data pager which is inside the control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datapager

I am creating A user control Where User Can Select file by and I am getting the File Name From DB, that control have Two Control List-View Data-Pager, this Control I am Using inside the Ajax module Popup, When I click To next button My Module Popup is closed, So I need to know, how i can detect the Data pager Event when some one Click on data pager.
this is my markup 
[
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ResumeControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="TheQueue.CustomWebControls.ResumeControl" %>

    
        
            
                
            
        
    
    
        <%-- Title Row --%>
        
            
                '>
            
            
                '></asp:Literal>
            </td> -->
        
        
            
                
                
            
            
        
        
        
            
                
                    
                        '>
                    
                    
                        '>
                    
                
                
            
            
                
                    
                        '>
                    
                    
                        '>
                    
                
            
        
        
            
                ' CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ResumeId")%>' />
            
        
    


    
        
        
        
    

]

Thsi is the code of base page
[
 
                                            
        
            
                
                    
                    
                
            
        
]

Answer (score 0):

We have had several issues implementing ajax popup. Finally we implemented a solution that doesn't require ajax / javascript / jquery / update panel / css tricks. This popup will not close until you close it. This has been working good for us for about a month or so. you might want to have a look:
[A modal popup with out using ajax, update panel, jquery or javascript- surprisingly this seems to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25220746/a-modal-popup-with-out-using-ajax-update-panel-jquery-or-javascript-surprisin)

Answer (score 0):

Main issue is data is rebinding and doing the full post back, just need to prevent full post back which solve the issue.